# OS Boundary Line shp export CSV with description and lat/lng

Tags: qgis, convert, coordinates, ordnance-survey, administrative-boundaries

I have found several post saying it is possible in QGIS to export OS Boundary Line shp files to csv's containing the boundary line in lat/lng (for use on Google map) along with the name of the area, some with instructions on how to do it but when ever I follow them it doesn't work for me.

I've only just downloaded QGIS so I don't know my way around as yet.

Steps so far:

Clicked "Add vector file", right click on layer and click "save as". Then select format "CSV", set CRS as "Layer CRS" and coordinate reference system as "WGS 84". I tried putting "GEOMETRY=AS_XY" and "GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ" in the layer field. Click ok and I get a file containing information about the polygons like name etc... but not the boundary line in lat/lng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the coordinates of a line or polygon layer by using the MMQGIS plugin:

```
MMQGIS -> Import/Export -> Geometry Export to CSV file
```

For Point Laers, you can add the coordinates directly using $x and $y in the field calculator.

For use in Google maps, you can also export to kml, which can e read by Google Maps:

```
MMQGIS -> Import/Export -> Google Maps KML Export
```

Be sure to set the target CRS to EPSG:4326 in all cases.

Comment: I have managed to export to a KML file which contains all the data I need. Thanks for answering though, I had tried the MMQGIS plugin but think I did it wrong.

Comment: I tried, it said I can't close my own question for so many hours.